# Setting homepage as a variable in package.json and make it change conditionally

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, package.json

How do I change/update `homepage` automatically without changing `package.json` in a React app?

I have A and B project, both projects have individual roots for Production Build, but they share a same root for Test Build. That's why I have different `homepage` configured for different environments. When I merge its Test Branch to its Prod Branch, I have to keep the `package.json` file different, which is not smart at all.

So, are there any ways that I can grab an Env variable and pass in?

Answer (score 4):

if you are using `create-react-app` version greater or equal than 0.9.0 in `package.json` remove `homepage`
and add `PUBLIC_URL` in your .env file

[Adding Custom Environment Variables](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)